# Change sort order of Duplicate sitecore item

Tags: sitecore-client

My requirement is to place newly created item on top. So I changed Sort order of newly created item programmatically using **item:added** event.

It works fine for when I create new item but not work when I duplicate an existing item.

So can someone suggest which pipeline I can use to change sort order of duplicated item programmatically ?

Comment: I know it's not an answer but this post contains nice explanation of Sitecore events so it may help you https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/6593/277

Comment: Maybe changing `subitems sorting` to use `Updated` time would be an option? https://www.geekhive.com/buzz/post/2015/05/how-to-automatically-sort-items-in-sitecore-cms/

Answer (score 9):

You don't need custom code.

You can set the subitems ordering for an item. I guess you need to have just for a part of tree to sort it by created day.

1. You need to right click on an item and choose Sorting-> Subitems Sorting

[image]

2. On new windows choose "Created" from DropList

[image]

3. Items will be sorted ascending by created date. To have items in descending order you need to press again Sort Items and from the DropList to choose Inverse.

[image]

Every time when you add new items it will be added on the top .

Comment: Actually this is not working for me. I implemented sorting using above steps.        But suppose there are 5 children in a node and i duplicate 4th child then the duplicated item gets created just above 4th item instead of top position. **But my requirement is to get the duplicated item created at top position.**

Comment: what happens when you follow these steps, I tried this solution and it works fine. What is the order in your case  ?

Comment: ok, I will update my answer.You need to create custom code for it.

Comment: In my case the duplicated item gets created just above the original item instead of top position.  Because I think **sort order** field value gets copied from original item. Thats why its not working.